# Degenerate perturbation theory: how to determine correction to eigenvector for this example?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

Consider the diagonalization of the following matrix as a series in $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$:
$$
A = A_0 + \epsilon A_1
$$
where
$$
A_0 = \frac{3}{2} \ \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 \\
 \end{matrix} \right] \qquad \& \qquad A_1 = \left[ \begin{matrix} 2 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{matrix} \right] \ .
$$

Suppose I am interested in finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors to $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^1)$. The characteristic polynomial for the eigenvalues $\lambda$ is
$$
\lambda^3  - ( 3 + 2 \epsilon ) \lambda^2 - \frac{\epsilon}{2}(3 - 2 \epsilon) \lambda + \frac{3}{2} \epsilon^2 = 0
$$
Writing the eigenvalues as a series in $\epsilon$ I find I get:
$$
\lambda_1 = 3 + \frac{3}{2} \epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2) \\
\lambda_2 = 0 - \frac{1}{2} \epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2) \\
\lambda_3 = 0 + \epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2) \\
$$
where $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ are degenerate if you turn off the perturbation with $\epsilon = 0$ (and so the perturbation "lifts" the degeneracy).

From there I take the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and the matrix $A$ and I solve for the eigenvectors $\vec{v}_i$ with the equation
$$
A \vec{v}_i = \lambda_i \vec{v}_{i}
$$
where I find that for example
$$
\vec{v}_i = \left[ \begin{matrix} -3/7 \\ 3/7 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right] + \epsilon \left[ \begin{matrix} a \\ \frac{1}{21} - a \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right] + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
$$
where $a$ can be any constant. The way I computed the above is to match powers of $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^1)$ in the equation $A \vec{v}_i = \lambda_i \vec{v}_{i}$ and I furthermore enforced that the bottom-most component is just 1.

**My question** I find that the eigenvalue equation $A \vec{v}_i = \lambda_i \vec{v}_{i}$ is satisfied at order $\epsilon^1$ *for any constant $a$*. What is puzzling to me is that $a$ can be any constant if we work to this order in perturbation theory. Why is this the case?

Is there a way of determining what the constant $a$ is without working to higher order in perturbation theory?